# Solr Facet only on Date excluding time

Tags: solr, faceted-search

I am trying to do a facet pivot on two fields timestamp and price and here is how my solr query is:
http://localhost:8888/solr/collection1/select?q=description%3laptop&wt=json&indent=true&facet=true&facet.pivot=timestamp,price&stats=true&stats.field=price&stats.facet=timestamp

This gives me the result as:

```
*"timestamp,price":[{
          "field":"timestamp",
          "value":"2015-06-02T07:12:29.044Z",
          "count":50,
          "pivot":[{
              "field":"price",
              "value":389.0,
              "count":9},
            {
              "field":"price",
              "value":388.0,
              "count":4},
            {
              "field":"price",
              "value":300.0.....*
```

I would like to change the timestamp format from 2015-06-02T07:12:29.044Z to 2015-06-02 when doing the facet so that the results come back as:

```
*"timestamp,price":[{
          "field":"timestamp",
          "value":"2015-06-02",
          "count":50,
          "pivot":[{
              "field":"price",
              "value":389.0,
              "count":9},
            {
              "field":"price",
              "value":388.0,
              "count":4},
            {
              "field":"price",
              "value":300.0.....*
```

So it facets by a day instead of multiple times a day. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an easy solution (but needs reindexing) is to put the date only value in another field (you can use [this update processor](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/6_5_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/update/processor/TrimFieldUpdateProcessorFactory.html) for this, or do it on the client side if you prefer), and then facet on that field.

Comment: That is what I was planning to do but wanted to know if I could somehow do it without creating a new column for only date.