# Is there a way to do stats in Solr by date range facet (without reindexing)?

Tags: solr

I would like to get solr stats of a `price` field (mean/median/std) within a `date range` facet. Is this possible? For example:

```
....solr/collection1/select?q=description:iphone
&facet=true
&facet.range=timestamp
&facet.range.start=NOW/MONTH
&facet.range.end=NOW/MONTH%2B1MONTH 
&facet.range.gap=%2B1DAY
&stats=true
&stats.field=price
```

Gives me the result:

```
{u'facet_ranges': {u'timestamp': {u'counts': [u'2017-06-01T00:00:00Z',
     79,
     u'2017-06-02T00:00:00Z',
     237,
   .... a bunch more stats for each day....

... a bunch of listings ....
 u'stats': {u'stats_fields': {u'price': {u'count': 28861,
    u'facets': {},
    u'max': 4000.0,
    u'mean': 161.44501277067423,
    u'min': 0.07000000029802322,
    u'missing': 2778,
    u'stddev': 143.61418183614867,
    u'sum': 4659464.513574429,
    u'sumOfSquares': 1347485766.7566266}}}
}
```

But I would like to see the stats broken down by day:

```
{u'facet_ranges': {u'timestamp': {u'2017-06-01T00:00:00Z':
         { "counts:79,
           "mean: 17.72,
           "median: 18,
           "stdev": 3.7,
          }
         u'2017-06-02T00:00:00Z':
         { "counts:237,
           "mean: 81.32,
           "median: 88,
           "stdev": 13.37,
        ....
```

Is this possible without [reindexing and creating another field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44647645)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [json facets](http://yonik.com/json-facet-api/#Range_Facet):

```
{ prices: 
   { type: range, 
     field: timestamp, 
     start: "NOW/MONTH", 
     end:"NOW/MONTH+1MONTH", 
     gap: "+1DAY",
     facet:{
            x : "avg(price)",
            y : "sum(price)"
          } 
   }
}
```

And to get the mean, avg etc per bucket look at the [Aggregate rangfunctions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Faceted+Search) you can use

Comment: Sorry for my slowness -- worked perfectly. Just had to do some testing before I accepted your answer. I was hesitant to use json.facet because the documentation says [it's still experimental](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Faceted+Search) but it works like a charm and will continue to use.